# delete "duplicate" entries and keep latest one

Tags: mysql

I forgot to add a unique index (process_id, result_id) to my table:

```
id, created_at, process_id, result_id, value
1, 2018-11-01, 1, 1, a
2, 2018-11-03, 1, 1, b
3, 2018-11-05, 2, 4, c
```

now I have multiple entries for the same combination of process_id and result_id.

In order to add the unique index, I need to get rid of the duplicates and only keep the latest entry (created_at) for each process/result pair.

How can I easily identify and delete the older duplicates?

I can identify all duplicates:

```
select pr.id, pr.created_at, prd.* 
from process_results pr
join (
    select process_id, result_id
    from process_results 
    group by process_id, result_id
    having count(*) > 1
) prd on pr.request_id = prd.request_id and pr.request_filter_id = prd.request_filter_id
```

but I am not sure how to delete all but the latest ones

expected result:

```
id, created_at, process_id, result_id, value
2, 2018-11-03, 1, 1, b
3, 2018-11-05, 2, 4, c
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1 
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2 
ON
    t1.created_at < t2.created_at 
AND t1.process_id = t2.process_id 
AND t1.result_id = t2.result_id    
;
```

To identify is the same

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2 
ON
    t1.created_at < t2.created_at 
AND t1.process_id = t2.process_id 
AND t1.result_id = t2.result_id
```

Comment: Is there a reason you used WHERE instead of ON?

Comment: @Uueerdo Not really. I just copy paste from an example. Work the same both ways

Comment: What happen chris I think you check this as the correct answer but then you remove it? Doesnt  solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE bad_rows.* FROM process_results AS bad_rows
                   INNER JOIN (
                      SELECT created_at,value,min(`process_id`) AS min_id FROM process_results GROUP BY process_id,result_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   ) AS good_rows ON good_rows.value = bad_rows.value AND good_rows.min_id != bad_rows.id
```